# A JavaScript  script only works on Internet Explorer when the Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I got a script working on Firefox 5 but not with Internet Explorer 9. 
When I just open the [Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_Developer_Tools) addon and try the same actions as before - it works. There is other JavaScript code on the page which is working, so it is just a part that isn't.

Is there something like the developer toolbar changing any options of Internet Explorer while running?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  It seems the odds were low :-)  ?

Comment: As everyone already mentioned the problem is that the console object doesn't exists in some instances/browsers. Try this console wrapper to avoid the errors, it gives you a cross-browser console logging solution - http://benalman.com/projects/javascript-debug-console-log/

Answer (score 53):

Without your having quoted any code, one has to guess.

My guess is that you're using `console.log` (or one of the other `console` methods) in your code. On IE8 and IE9, the `console` object doesn't exist until/unless the developer tools are open. Strange but true.

You should be getting script errors along the lines of "`console` is undefined" when you don't have the dev tools open.

Because of this, and because `console` doesn't exist in every browser (certainly not IE6 or IE7, which still combined make up about 18% of the general browsing users), it's best not to include them in production code or to check proactively that `console` exists before using it.

Comment: Thank you for saving me (__insert_too_much_time_here__) hours, @T.J. Crowder!  Your answer was the first (and last) in my search for what could be causing me this issue... Note to self: check for console before using!

Comment: Thanks for this... really saved me. Funny how even msdn couldn't answer this question.

Comment: Man, I can't give you enough upvotes... Thanks a million! - Guys, remember to upvote also the question :P

Comment: THANK YOU! I could simply not understand what was causing this error! And why do Internet Explorer not throw any errors! Such a bitch!

Comment: If I found aladdin's magic lamp one day, I'll ask for removing IE from history.

Answer (score 7):

Is your script accessing or running any methods that are only available when the developer toolbar is open, such as `console.log`? For example, running `console.log` when `console` is undefined because the developer toolbar isn't open will cause an exception to be thrown.

Comment: Thanks, it was console.log causing my problems!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [in a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742781/why-javascript-only-works-after-opening-developer-tools-in-ie-once), use this code (in a script tag at the top of your page before other script tags, preferably):

```
(function() {
    var method;
    var noop = function () {};
    var methods = [
        'assert', 'clear', 'count', 'debug', 'dir', 'dirxml', 'error',
        'exception', 'group', 'groupCollapsed', 'groupEnd', 'info', 'log',
        'markTimeline', 'profile', 'profileEnd', 'table', 'time', 'timeEnd',
        'timeStamp', 'trace', 'warn'
    ];
    var length = methods.length;
    var console = (window.console = window.console || {});

    while (length--) {
        method = methods[length];

        // Only stub undefined methods.
        if (!console[method]) {
            console[method] = noop;
        }
    }
}());
```

or find a more up to date version of this same code here:
https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/src/js/plugins.js

This just solved that same issue for me.