# Google Maps Not Loading in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-9

Internet Explorer is not loading maps but if you hit F12 and open developer tools then hit refresh it does load the maps.

http://www.jaycodesign.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/demos/StreetView/

It should be loading the maps via the jQuery code below, but it doesn't.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {      
        console.log("doc ready");               
        load_map_and_street_view_from_address("12 Boston Rd, Boston");

        $('#change_street').click(function(){
            $('form').submit();
        });

    });
```

How do I make IE load the maps?

Answer (score 0):

Got it

Removed console.log("doc ready");

saw this just after I posted

[A JavaScript  script only works on Internet Explorer when the Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889376/a-javascript-script-only-works-on-internet-explorer-when-the-internet-explorer?rq=1)