# LOGOUT only works on Internet Explorer(11) when the Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar is visible

Tags: javascript, ember.js

LOGOUT only works on Internet Explorer(11) when the Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar is visible
it working fine with chrome i tried all options from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889376/a-javascript-script-only-works-on-internet-explorer-when-the-internet-explorer) but its not working
is anything wrong in code ?
I AM USING `Ember` 
here is code

```
logoutPage(){
      let parts = document.location.href.split('/');
      let logOutUrl='/abc/unsecured/j_spring_logout'
      window.location =logOutUrl;
}
```

am calling above function from

```
<a id="session_Logout" {{action "logoutPage"}} style="cursor: pointer;">{{toplevel.label}}</a>
```

Comment: Run your app in IE11 mode, you've set the document mode to IE9 or earlier. Or remove all references to `console` from the code.

Comment: removed all references to console from the code but Ember uses console internally in js and app is runnig in Edge(default) its not showing IE11 option it shows 10,9,8 and  Edge(default)

Comment: Is that close to your real logout code? Only setting `window.location` to something and nothing else? (What's `parts` for, then?) If yes, can you set `window.location` to something else in another context? If no, can you pinpoint which statement exactly fails?

Comment: am using `j_spring_security_logout` so using that url it passes to filter and filter invalid session by `session.invalidate()` it works fine with other browser issue for IE

Comment: You may find these answers helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245547/document-location-does-not-change-the-webpage-in-ie9

Comment: @ Steve H. it is not working without opening developer option it works fine with developer option and it shows url in network while logout but after closing developer window not working

Answer (score 1):

Hi we also facing the same issue. When we check it with developer tool the IE version become 5 instead of IE 11 so we just added the

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />
```

in the header section of sign out page. which force the page to use IE11 and its working fine.